# queryProductDetailsAsync returns empty list in production version (Google Play Billing)

Tags: google-play, in-app-billing, google-play-console, android-billing, play-billing-library

I'm facing an issue, queryProductDetailsAsync returns empty list in production version, But it's working well for internal testers.

I published the app and it was approved yesterday. Also the app is active and I can see it on play store.

What could be the problem ?

any help is appreciated.

thank you.

edit: issue wasn't resolved, but it turned out that it already works for my friends, so the problem was only on my side, thanks anyway.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

queryProductDetailsAsync would return empty list if you have not set up offers for your subscriptions correctly. can you check your subscriptions details in google play console ?

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."